# jQuery autocomplete tagging new tag design pattern

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to create a tagging like system in my application.  This would seem to be a common design pattern but I'm not finding much in the way of examples when it comes to storing new tags from input.  Specifically I'm trying to find the most elegant way of storing new tags in the database from the user submitted input.  So an example from the jQuery UI multiple remotes page.

```
Western Jackdaw, New Tag, Eurasian Wryneck, Another New Tag
```

What is the most efficient way of inserting the new tags in the database?  I want to do more actions on the new tags after the insert so I need to have a response for any tags that are new.

It seems like there are two ways to approach this.  One would be to do a js object solution client side that would designate whether a tag is from the server or new when the form is submitted.  The second would be to just submit the tags and let the server figure it out.

Thanks.

Comment: So I think I might be over-thinking this.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but see this URL. I think it help full to you.

https://github.com/jstayton/jquery-marcopolo

**Example**

http://jstayton.github.com/jquery-marcopolo/example1.html